# how to merge cells vertically with bootstrap-tables?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap-tables tool, a library itself, and below to assemble a table like the image, but I'm not getting results, would you know what structure I can do to assemble the table?

[image: Table Example]

I try this code:

```js
let arrData = [
  {
    name: "Alan",
    food: ["Melon", "Hamburguer"]
  }
]

$('#merged').bootstrapTable({
    data: arrData,
    columns: [{
                title: "Name",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "name"
            },{
                title: "Food",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "food"
            }]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <table class="table" id="merged">
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#data), you can use `_<field>_rowspan`. However, you would need to define a separate item holding only `food: "Hamburger"`, as I did not found anything about using Arrays:

```js
let arrData = [
  {
    name: "Alan",
    _name_rowspan: 2,
    food: "Melon"
  },
  {
    food: "Hamburger"
  }
]

$('#merged').bootstrapTable({
    data: arrData,
    columns: [{
                title: "Name",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "name"
            },{
                title: "Food",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "food"
            }]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <table class="table" id="merged">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me, this is really hard to understand in the documentation